# Float to Integer Python

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

Hello I am currently running this simple code in python:

```
k = 2
kRadius= k / 2
int(kRadius)
print(kRadius)
```

But I need kRadius to be as an integer. The int function isn't working as kRadius is being saved as 1.0. I've tried many other functions such as ceil and floor from the math library but still getting the same result as a float. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: `kRadius= k // 2`

Answer (score 2):

Here is your anwser:

```
kRadius = int(kRadius)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the divide operator, it converts the result automatically to a float. In your code, when you say, int(kRadius) it calls it as an integer, but it doesn't set a new value for kRadius. To reassign Kradius as an integer you have to say

```
k = 2
kRadius = k / 2
kRadius = int(kRadius)
print(kRadius)
```

or you could convert it into an integer while you first assign the value to kRadius

```
k = 2
kRadius = int(k / 2)
print(kRadius)
```